# Cómo corregir hora del cliente con su zona horaria y zona horaria del servidor en un sitio web

Tags: php, javascript, momentjs

Qué tal comunidad, tengo unas dudas y para que me entiendan las planteare con el siguiente ejemplo.
**Ejemplo.** En el servidor son las 11:40 con zona horaria Japón, y un usuario x tiene la hora mal ¿Puedo detectar su zona horaria? Y ahora ¿Puedo partir de la hora y zona horaria de Japón para que mi usuario tenga la hora correcta osea las 21:40?

Comment: En ciertos casos si el usuario tiene la hora mal el navegador no puede conectarse, a mi me pasaba mas que todo en las computadoras del colegio, pero imagino que eso pasaba solo porque eran dinosaurios prehistoricos.

Comment: Pues yo pienso que lo mejor no seria usar la hora de la persona si no requerirle al usuario en que region se encuentra, y atravez de tu servidor usar la zona horaria del servidor (que supongo sera UTC), y compararla con la zona horaria de esa persona para calcular la diferencia de tiempo (discordancia de tiempo) que hay entre la hora calculada de esa timezone del servidor y la zona horaria de la persona, de esta manera aunque la persona tenga mal la hora en su dispositivo tu podras hacer uso de esta informacion para resolverlo.

Comment: Esto aplica para la timezone que mencionas, siendo que tu servidor al estar sincronizado con japon (por ejemplo), puedes obtener la zona horaria de la otra persona atravez de preguntarle su timezone y calculando desde el mismo servidor esa hora pero de acuerdo a esa timezone, de esa manera le entregarias al usuario la zona correcta en base a la hora de tu servidor (japon).

Comment: Bien, dispongo de la hora y zona horaria de Japón, y ya tengo la zona horaria (**Por ejemplo.** México) del usuario. Con esos datos ¿Cómo le entrego la hora correcta? ¿Cuál es el código?

Comment: ese es el punto, esa es mi idea, pero nunca he trabajado con moment.js xd, por lo que eso se queda en solo una idea, ya que en `php` no me he puesto a mirar mucho como obtener fechas u horas, de todas maneras si el usuario tiene descuadrado su horario local, para acomodarlo debes preguntarle desde el frontend cual es su zona horaria y en base a eso calcularlo en el servidor el cual tendra la hora correcta, tambien de una vez enviar su hora equivocada, y asi comparar la diferencia entre la correcta y la equivocada segun el servidor, luego le devuelves esa hora al frontend.

Answer (score -1):

```
ini_set('date.timezone','America/Lima'); //zona horaria seteada America/Lima
echo date("h:i A"); //Muestra la hora actual
```

Comment: Se considera de baja calidad responder solo con codigo, porfavor leer [answer].

Comment: Eso es del lado del servidor con eso le mando la hora al cliente y puedo enviar la zona horaria, ahora cómo le haría por el lado del cliente, puedo obtener la zona horaria con moment.js y es México, pero mi hora está mal, entonces ¿Cómo le hago con moment.js?